# jQuery Validation in a dialog using .load()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-dialog

I have 2 ASP.Net pages, one contains an empty div that will hold the jQuery dialog window and the required code to .load() controls on another page which contains the controls I would like to validate. (They are ASP.Net textboxes contained in regular HTML tables)
The below code is used to open the dialog and load the second page containing the controls:

```
 $(".open-dialog").click(function () {
    $("#hfAddressHash").val($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }) //Stops annoying caching problem.
    $('#dialog').load('jQueryLoad.aspx?Hash='123' + ' #divTest');
    dlg.dialog('open');
  });
```

An example of the controls displayed on the second page are as follows:

```
<table>  
      <tr> 
        <th>Source System(s)</th>
        <td width="160"><asp:Label ID="lblSource" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
        <th>Firm</th>
        <td><div class="draggable"><asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server"></asp:Label></div></td>
        <td width="20"><asp:ImageButton ID="imgArrow" runat="server" CssClass="copyAddress Country" ImageUrl="/Intranet/_Resources/Icons/arrow.png" /></td>
        <th>Firm</th>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" CssClass="droppable" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>
```

I would like to make the above 'txtCountry' control a required field for example using jQuery validation.
My validation and dialog functionality code is as follows:

```
  $("#form1").validate();

  if ($("#txtCountry").is(":visible")) {

    $("#txtCountry").rules("add", { required: true });
  }



  var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({

    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 820,
    width: 860,
    buttons: {
      Cancel: function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog('close');
      },
      Submit: function () {
        if (!$('#form1').valid()) { // Validate on Submit
          return false;
        }


        var names = [];
        $('#cblTypes input:checked').each(function () {
          names.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "AddressView.aspx/postAddress",
          data: '{"OwnerRef":"' + $("#hfClient").val() + '"}',
          async: false,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (msg) {
            form1.submit();
          },
          error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

On the press of the 'Submit' button contained in the jquery dialog, the page does not validate the 'txtCountry' control as intended to. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see right away. In your ajax settings, you have some json in the `data` part.

```
data: '{"OwnerRef":"' + $("#hfClient").val() + '"}',
```

Change it to:

```
data: { OwnerRef: $("#hfClient").val() },
```